# ¿Como limitar el intervalo de fechas disponibles en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datepicker

Quiero agregar una fecha de vencimiento a mi formulario, es decir que solo permita seleccionar maximo 5 dias apartir de la fecha del sistema.

```
 dtpFechaVenci.Text = DateTime.Now
    FechaVencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFechaVenci)
    FechaVencimiento += Today.AddDays(5)
```

intente esto, pero no da los resultados esperados

Comment: yo ni entiendo el problema

Comment: ok, x ejemplo hoy es 18 de febrero, necesito que en el datapicker solo permita seleccionar como maximo 5 dias despues, es decir que me deje seleccionar hasta el 23 de febrero

Comment: lo acabo de probar y me marca error,

Comment: Acceso de miembro no compartido, miembro de constante, miembro de enumeracion, o tipo anidado, atravez de una instancia, la expresion de calificacion no se evaluara, La variable ReadOnly no puede ser destino de una asignacion.

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar la propiedad [`MaxDate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) del `DateTimePicker`:

```
dtpFechaVenci.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5)
```

Para limitar la fecha mínima, se hace uso de la propiedad [`MinDate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
dtpFechaVenci.MinDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-5)
```

Comment: perfecto amigo, muchas gracias